# Accessing an element by index in a nested array returns undefined

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, nested-lists

I am currently working on copying data from one row to another with spaces between for data that needs to be entered manually. I am trying to copy most of the data in the currently selected row and paste it to a blank row without appending any new rows. The issue I'm currently having is when I try to directly access the values in a nested array. The array will log correctly when called but the values in the array will not show individually unless I am using the getValue function but that only shows the first item of the array.

This is what the code looks like now:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const activeCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();


function test() {
  let activeRow = sheet.getRangeList([activeCell.getA1Notation() + ':' + activeCell.offset(0,1).getA1Notation(), activeCell.offset(0,3).getA1Notation(), activeCell.offset(0,5).getA1Notation() + ':' + activeCell.offset(0,7).getA1Notation()]).getRanges();
  Logger.log(activeRow[0][0].getValue())
};
```

This is giving me the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined. However when I only use one index in the Logger such as:

```
Logger.log(activeRow[0].getValue())
```

it gives me the first value in the indexed array.

If I change the function to getValues as well as only using one index such as:

```
Logger.log(activeRow[0].getValues())
```

it returns an array of the values of the first two cells in the row.

I understand the double-indexing is what's causing the issue I'm just not sure why it's causing an issue but I would like to be able to access the data individually so I can then copy the data to the new row.

I am also open to further optimization or a different way of accomplishing this that I may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sh.getActiveCell();
  const r = sh.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  Logger.log(r[0][0])
}

Execution log
1:46:41 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:46:42 PM  Info    10.0
1:46:43 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |